# When installing a delta shower cartridge does it matter if the two small holes in the back of cartridges metal plate be vertical or horizontal

Tags: shower, cartridge

Shower cartridge holes should be horizontal or vertical

Comment: It usually matters but you need to follow the model-specific instructions.   Delta's instructions are quite cryptic.  If you add the model and a copy of the instructions to your Question, maybe people here can help you to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely matters which way the holes line up when replacing a cartridge. The manufacturers are really good at making it hard for you to install the cartridge the wrong way. There are usually grooves or arrow notches that have to be lined up correctly or the cartridge won't seat into the valve. Your instructions should explain this.